# Why is the content of my contenteditable div disappearing?

Tags: javascript, html, meteor

The code:

**post_page.js:**

```
Template.postPage.events({
 // Updating a post
 'submit form': function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var post = {
      title: $(e.target).find('[name=title]').val(),
      content: $(e.target).find('[name=content]').val()
    };

    Posts.update(this._id, {$set: post});
  },

  'click .move-up': function(e) {
    // Moving up a post
    e.preventDefault();

    var prevPost = Posts.findOne({position: this.position - 1});

    if (prevPost) {
      Posts.update(prevPost._id, {$set: {position: prevPost.position + 1}});
      Posts.update(this._id, {$set: {position: this.position - 1}});
    }
  },

(...)

Template.postPage.rendered = function() {
  // Plugin to turn the text area into a contenteditable div
  var editor;
  $(function() {
   editor = new Simditor({
    textarea: $("#input-content"),
    placeholder: "...",
    pasteImage: true,
    toolbar: ["title", "bold", "italic", "underline", "link", "image", "indent", "outdent"],
    upload: {
      url: "/upload"
    }
  });
```

**post_page.html:**

```
<template name="postPage">
  <div class="posts">
    <div class="post">
      <div class="post-content">
        <span>title: {{title}}, position: {{position}}</span>
        <a class="move-up" href="javascript:;">Move Up</a>
        <a class="move-down" href="javascript:;">Move Down</a>
        <a href="{{pathFor 'postPage'}}">See Post</a>
        <a class="save-file" href="javascript:;">Save Post</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <form class="form" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Title</label>
      <input name="title" type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Enter email" value="{{title}}">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Content</label>
      <textarea name="content" class="form-control" rows="3">{{content}}</textarea>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default submit">Submit</button>   </form> </template>
```

Is a single page app and everything works but for some reason the content of the contenteditable `div` disappears if I `move up` a `post` that isn't the one currently being displayed (the content in textarea remains and it comes back if I re-render the page):

[image]

What could be causing this? How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving the post up/down causes the template to re-render completely and I suspect that because the `simditor` expects the DOM to persist, it either doesn't *re-run* on `rendered` or runs before Meteor's *preserve-inputs* package has repopulated the `textarea`.

You can try to work around the problem (until Meteor gets the Blaze templating engine up) by wrapping your re-rendering sensitive area (at least the `textarea` and possibly the complete DOM generated by `simditor`) in [`{{#constant}}`](http://docs.meteor.com/#constant). If you know the exact DOM elements you want to preserve, then you can also use [`preserve` to prevent them from being re-rendered](http://docs.meteor.com/#template_preserve).